# Bootstrap stack elements top and bottom on mobile, sidebar on desktop

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have three elements in my layout, `top bar`, `content` and `bottom bar`.

I am using twitter bootstrap 4

On mobile I want them to stack as such:

```
top bar
content
bottom bar
```

on desktop I want this:

```
content    top bar
           bottom bar
```

a visual guide:
[image]

How do I even? I can't seem to get them to line up properly and I'm way down the bottom of a rabbit hole here so I'm asking the stack.

code:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
 <div class=container>
  <div class=row>
   <div class="col-12 col-md-5 order-md-2">
    <h3>Top Bar</h3>
   </div>
  
   <div class="col-12 col-md-7 order-md-1">
    <h3>Content</h3>
    <p>A bit of Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ac turpis ac massa mollis posuere.</p>
    <p>Duis urna purus, sagittis eget fermentum in, aliquam sed est.</p> 
    <p>Praesent imperdiet a nisi at aliquet. Curabitur velit mi, vestibulum sed molestie non, egestas sit amet elit.</p>
    <p>Donec commodo tincidunt ligula sed pharetra. Etiam efficitur blandit laoreet. Aliquam eu pellentesque dui, eu accumsan dolor. Vestibulum congue facilisis porta. Praesent venenatis, risus eu mollis varius, erat est ornare felis, in rhoncus arcu metus eget ante.</p>
   </div>
  
   <div class="col-12 col-md-5 order-md-2 offset-md-7">
    <h3>Bottom Bar</h3>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either disable flex on Bootstrap or add a modifier on the row and set 
`display: block;`

Float the middle child left, and then float the top and bottom bar right. Also remove the offset so it fills in the gap gracefully.

This should get you what you want on desktop; of course you will need to remove those for your mobile breakpoint.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class=row style="display: block;">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-5 order-md-2" style="float:right;">
            <h3>Top Bar</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-md-7 order-md-1" style="float:left;">
            <h3>Content</h3>
            <p>A bit of Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ac turpis ac massa mollis posuere.</p>
            <p>Duis urna purus, sagittis eget fermentum in, aliquam sed est.</p> 
            <p>Praesent imperdiet a nisi at aliquet. Curabitur velit mi, vestibulum sed molestie non, egestas sit amet elit.</p>
            <p>Donec commodo tincidunt ligula sed pharetra. Etiam efficitur blandit laoreet. Aliquam eu pellentesque dui, eu accumsan dolor. Vestibulum congue facilisis porta. Praesent venenatis, risus eu mollis varius, erat est ornare felis, in rhoncus arcu metus eget ante.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-md-5 order-md-2"  style="float:right;" >
            <h3>Bottom Bar</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Legend. I had worked around it by duplicating the element and using the bootstrap display properties `d-none` `d-md-block` etc, but this is way better thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `order` class to reorder your elements when changing viewports.

Check it here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering

Comment: It's a combination of the `.order` class and also making sure your main content has a larger `.col` value in desktop devices.

Comment: The `order` classes work in terms of moving the elements horizontally but when the `content` block has more content, it pushes the `bottom bar` element down to level with the bottom of the `content` block. Run the code snippet in fullscreen and resize the window to see what I mean.